# Error:Unable to obtain debug bridge in android studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

After updating **Android Studio** to **2.0 l** am getting this **error** unable to obtain debug bridge and Android Device Monitor does not open. Anyone faced this error before?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just open sdk manager and installed all android sdk tools and done.

Comment: Yes its working.. But we may install tools as per our Requirement not required to install All tools.

Comment: I just installed all the sdk tools . but still i m having error saying "unable to obtain debug bridge"

Comment: For me problem still exists :(

Answer (score 3):

Check whether you need to install "Android Sdk Platform Tools" in the Android SDK Manager.

Somehow, after installing Android Studio from the bundle (for Linux) I lacked the "platform-tools" directory in "Android/Sdk", where the adb executable resides. Installing the platform tools helped. It was easier to find in the standalone sdk manager.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you deleted the adb.exe (it might be your antivirus who deleted it),that resided in the platform tools in the android sdk folder.

What you need to do is to delete the current platform-tools in the sdk manager program and re install it all over again.

Comment: That's exactly what happened to me. What's the path where my platform tools would be locates so I can find and delete it. Thanks

Comment: @CraigGallagher On my Mac it's /Users/<User>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

Answer (score 1):

I installed the right sdk version that matched my virtual device android version

Answer (score 0):

I am also running the same problem when update android studio from 1.4 to 1.5 stable version. When I run adb command from terminal then i found following error :

bash: ./adb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

After R&d I found that this error occurs due to unsupported architecture. In my case:

I am using ubuntu14.04 LTS 32-bit. I observed that after updation, lib folder under platform-tools converted to lib64. I think above error occurs due to 32-bit architecture because after updation 32-bit support removed.

For permanent solution upgrade you system to 64-bit architecture.
Quick solution is to replace the updated platform-tools folder with old one that containing the lib folder instead of lib64.

I think 32-bit architecture support for android development stopped by google for future releases. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am phase these error when updating **Android-SDK Plateform-Tools 23.1** in Android SDK Manager

i am worked on ubuntu 14.04 [32bit] that is not supporting with Plateform-Tools 23.1 it is only supporting in 64bit Operating System architecture that's why downgrade my Plateform-tools 23.0

it works perfect...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to: *Android Studio Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK:*

> If path for SDK are text in red, change to your SDK folder and click `***APPLY***`

Answer (score 0):

Open the standalone SDK manager and install the platform tools package.