# ERROR while running application in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

This is the error while running application. What to do?, any help please
[image: ERROR while running application in Android Studio]

Comment: sync project with gradle file..Add dependencies properly.

Comment: Sync, Clean and rebuild will work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012226/errorunable-to-obtain-debug-bridge-in-android-studio

Comment: Try to open sdk manager and installed all android sdk tools and done.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you do not have permission to execute adb command. Try to change permissions for adb using chmod and give execute permission. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the suggestions provided here:
[ADB Connection Error: Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to detect adb version, adb output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236449/adb-connection-error-unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-server)

Seems like a problem with the platform tools version you are using.