# Waiting for adb Android studio

Tags: android, adb

I am using Android Studio Version 1.5.2 on Windows 10.
Earlier it was working fine but now this problem pops up.

> CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevationWaiting > for adb.Unable to obtain debug bridge.

I tried  `adb kill-server` and started it again and even updated Android Sdk Platform tool to version 24.0.2. However, when I connect my Device,it doesn't show in android monitor .

I have already enabled usb debugging.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012226/errorunable-to-obtain-debug-bridge-in-android-studio

Comment: Its same but none of the solution is working for me.When in re-installed adb lib64 file is created and my system supports 64 bit file so i dont think its causing any problem because of that

Comment: open task manager and delete adb from task manager and start again. Try using different ports or different wire to connect your phone

Comment: I tried it but its showing the same error.Although i saw in the task manager adb(32 bit) but 32bit shouldn't be the cause of the problem i believe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

close android studio,
right click on Android Studio icon and select ***"Run As Administrator"*** because **The requested operation requires elevation** is related to permissions and process level

Comment: Thank you very much It worked.But why does it need such permissions and process level that we need to run as administrator??

Comment: @Zen i am not sure why is this, it may creates some tmp files on C: or any other processing that Windows consider critical and requires such level.

Comment: My app is not running on my device. Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159166/app-not-running-on-hardware-device-in-android-studio?noredirect=1#comment65679283_39159166